# Best way to fit a lot of stuff onto one page

Tags: user-interface, html

I have created a webpage, but my boss came back saying that the page is too busy. I was just wanting some ideas of how to split up the page e.g. Accordian, tabs etc. What tactics have you implemented to break up a page into different sections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already named 2 of the most popular ones: accordions and tabs. The other one you're missing is "rotators".

Here's an example of one: http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery_image_slider_plugin (also happens to be a good jQuery plugin).

Keep in mind that you can also reduce clutter by using more vertical space and embracing scrolling. Not everything has to be above the fold.